# "To refuse oneself" vs "to refuse"

Tags: meaning, verbs, differences

In which cases can we use "to refuse oneself" instead of "to refuse"? Can you use "oneself" to give more emphasis to the sentence, or are you only allow to use it when you refuse something done to you?

In particular, I know this example is acceptable:

> I **refuse myself** more food than I can fit in a small plate

But can you use it like this?

> While the expression is acceptable, I **refuse [myself]** to say it.

Comment: simply, **don't say** "refuse myself". it's that simple. it's unclear and clumsy. instead if you really have to, use the four-=word pattern "refuse to allow myself..." "refuse to allow myself more food" "refuse to allow myself to say it", etc. note that **deny myself** is fairly common and does work, if it is what you actually mean.

Comment: The phrase is _recuse oneself_, and it's legal; it means to decline to participate in some legal proceeding because one has an interest in the outcome.

Comment: @JoeBlow Why do you advise against using a commonly used verb? I cannot find any mention about this use being obsolete in a [dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/refuse_1). It sounds as if you advise someone to keep his language as sober as possible, but doesn't that impoverish the language itself? If I can refuse my friend food, I can refuse myself food — why not?

Comment: Hey Oerk!  "refuse myself" is confusing.  the form "refuse to allow myself..." is very common.  the form "deny myself" is also common.  when you have common, ubiquitous forms, and a form that sounds confusing to a native ear, I can only say "don't use it"!

Comment: @oerk “I refuse myself [food]” is not commonly used. I cannot recall ever hearing it used in my life. Using _deny_ here would be much, much more idiomatic and common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To *refuse something (to) someone* means that you make sure that that *someone* does not have access to that *something*.

This (ditransitive) use is complete different from *refuse to do something*, which means that one will *not do something*.

So, in short, no, you can not use *myself* the way you did in the second sentence.

Completely unrelated, you *can* add *myself* to just about *any* sentence to emphasize the fact that *you* do it instead of someone else:

> Since no-one else offers, I will pay the bill myself!
>   The plumber was late, so I fixed the pipe myself.

However, you have to be careful with the placement of *myself*. If you want to emphasize that you, yourself, have decide not to use an expression, even though it is correct, you can say:

> While the expression is acceptable, I, myself, refuse to say it.

This way, you avoid any confusion about *refuse to do something* and *refuse something to someone*.